# Compare elements of two arrays of Object

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, generics

I am trying to build a generic merge method, part of a mergeSort algorithm but I am stuck on how to deal with the comparison.

This is my code so far:

```
public static Object[] merge(Object[] left, Object[] right) {
    ArrayList<Object> output = new ArrayList<>(left.length > right.length ? left.length : right.length);

    int leftIndex = 0; 
    int rightIndex = 0;

    while (leftIndex < left.length && rightIndex < right.length) {
        if ( left[leftIndex].compareTo(right[rightIndex]) ) { <-- the problem
            output.add(left[leftIndex]);
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            output.add(right[rightIndex]);
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }

    //add left over elements
    output.addAll(Arrays.copyOfRange(left, leftIndex, left.length));
    output.addAll(Arrays.copyOfRange(right, rightIndex, right.length));

    return output.toArray();
}
```

This doesn't work though, the Object class doesn't have any "compare" method.

One idea I had is to pass a Comparable as an argument to the merge method and use it in the condition, though it doesn't feel to me like the best way to achieve this goal.

Another one that I didn't manage to make work is something as the following:

```
public static Object[] merge(Object[]<T implements Comparable> left, 
                             Object[]<implements Comparable> right) {
```

Essentially trying to state that the elements of the array MUST implement the Comparable interface, though I am not really sure how to do this.

How else can this be done, perhaps in a more elegant way?

Comment: Maybe `Comparable[]` ?

Comment: You're suggesting to change the Object type to Comparable type in the whole method? That could be a good idea. I have to think if there are cons to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Comparable` you can do

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] merge(T[] left, T[] right) {
```

or, if you want to use it with classes that don't implement `Comparable`, you can supply a `Comparator`, like

```java
public static <T> T[] merge(T[] left, T[] right, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
```

The implementations inside of `Arrays.sort` do something similar.

Comment: Thank you Anderson, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.
I couldn't test it yet 'cause I got stuck on another problem: comparable returns an int while I thought it returned a boolean.

if I manage to make it work and test your solution I will let you know

Comment: Hi @Marco; when the two given parameters are equal it returns `0`, so you can use `a.compareTo(b) == 0` for an equality check. Less than `0` will mean that `a` is "smaller" than `b`, and a value greater than `0` will mean that `a` is "larger" than `b`.